# PHP API retrieve data

Tags: php, ajax, api

I am trying to create my own API in PHP.

Calling my API:

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'api.php',
       data: {'param': 'test',
              'param2': 'test'},
       type: 'GET',
       success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
       }
});
```

But how can I get the param (test) in my API? I thought it is in `$_POST` but its empty.

Comment: `type: 'GET',` <-- what makes you think the data would be in `$_POST`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be available in `$_POST`, you need to send the data through POST:

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'api.php',
       data: {'param': 'test',
              'param2': 'test'},
       type: 'POST',                 // THIS LINE. Can be GET, POST, or PUT
       success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
       }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so type POST it is in $_POST and GET is in $_GET
But how could I get the data on PUT or delete?

Comment: You can use `POST`, `GET`, and `PUT` with this method in jQuery 1.9.0 and greater. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

If type='GET' then your data should be found in $_GET

Comment: Thanks, so type POST it is in $_POST and GET is in $_GET
But how could I get the data on PUT or delete?

Comment: PUT or DELETE are not True method types for HTTP Forms, they are just handled inside the code using other keys to fake it :P

Comment: use $_REQUEST and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] to check all kinds of stuff

Comment: Is it also possible to get the data on PUT or DELETE?

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper array, if inside the ajax request you set the Type to POST, use
`$_POST['key']`, if you set it to GET, use `$_GET['key']`

Comment: Thanks, so type POST it is in $_POST and GET is in $_GET
But how could I get the data on PUT or delete?